# I need to stop animation between multiple clicks

Tags: jquery

I have this function and the function: `stopPropagation();` doesn't do what I need. No error message, it just doesn't work, the propagations happens when you click the elements several times.

**Update:** I need to stop the propagation when you click the element several times, maybe the "propagation" is not the right word for this.

**Problem and what I need:** when you click the element several times the animations (hide and show) happens several times. I need it to happen just one time

It is the real code:

```
$('#block-menu-menu-men-gesto ul.menu > li a.parent').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#block-menu-menu-men-gesto ul.menu ul:visible').hide("slow"); 
  $(this).parent().find('ul').show("slow");
  console.log('1111');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Just doesn't work - explain! What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: @PraveenKumar the propagations happens when you click the elements several times.

Comment: Why you use stopPropagation for this code?

Comment: @JqueryKing I need to stop the propagation when you click the element several times.

Comment: Show us the full you wrote???

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of "propagation"... What are you actually trying to achieve ? Do you want to execute the code only on the first click ?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: I believe he's trying to wait "slow" animation to finish in order to allow new clicks to be processed.... I could be wrong though

Comment: @Brewal when you click the element several times the animations (hide and show) happens several times. I need it to happen just one time.

Comment: `stopPropagation()` means: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. Do you need this?

Comment: Then maybe you just want to `stop()` before `hide("slow")` and `show("slow")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when you click the element several time the animations (hide and show) happens several times. I need it to happen just one time

To achieve this you can use `stop()` to clear any queued animations before starting the next. Try this:

```
$('#block-menu-menu-men-gesto ul.menu > li a.parent').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#block-menu-menu-men-gesto ul.menu ul:visible').stop().hide("slow"); 
    $(this).parent().find('ul').stop().show("slow");
});
```

`stopPropagation` is used to prevent the event bubbling up the DOM, which is not relevant to your issue.